# Add CSS class name to body tag for a checkout step

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, javascript, css

Does anyone know of a reliable way in which I could add a css class name on the body tag for a specific checkout step? For example  `my-custom-step` or `payment-step`.

I was thinking I could use jQuery in a [JavaScript mixin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) for when a checkout step is initiated, i.e. `stepNavigator.next()`.  But I don't think this is very reliable, as a user can land on a step from anywhere using the `#` symbol in the url, i.e. `example.com/checkout/#payment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative way, with a module which adds a component. Instead of any type of overriding of the Magento-core. Tested with 2.1.x to 2.2.6.

I assume you know how to create a basic Magento 2-module. We'll call this one Daan_CustomBodyClass:

Create `Daan/CustomBodyClass/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`:

We'll add a custom component here to progressBar:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="progressBar" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="daan-custom-body-class" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Daan_CustomBodyClass/js/view/custom-body-class</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Create `Daan/CustomBodyClass/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-body-class.js`:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'jquery/jquery.hashchange'
], function ($, _, ko, Component, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    var steps = stepNavigator.steps;

    return Component.extend({
        steps: steps,

        /**
         * Initially we add a 'shipping-step' class to the body on Step 1.
         * After switching to billing we remove that class and add a 'payment-step' class.
         */
        initialize: function() {
            this._super();

            $(document.body).addClass('shipping-step');

            $(window).hashchange(_.bind(function() {
                if (window.location.hash === '#shipping') {
                    $(document.body)
                        .removeClass('payment-step')
                        .addClass('shipping-step');
                }
                if (window.location.hash === '#payment') {
                    $(document.body)
                        .removeClass('shipping-step')
                        .addClass('payment-step');
                }
            }));

            return this;
        }
    });
}
);
```

This should add a class 'shipping-step' to the document body on the Shipping Step and replace it with 'payment-step' whenever is switched to the Payment Step.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Copy file from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/progress-bar.js

and paste into

> app/design/frontend/Namespace/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/progress-bar.js

find following code

```
isProcessed: function (item) {
   return stepNavigator.isProcessed(item.code);
}
```

and replace with this

```
isProcessed: function (item) {
   var itemCode = item.code;
   if (itemCode == "shipping") {
       jQuery('body').addClass('payment-step');
   } else {
       jQuery('body').removeClass('payment-step');
   }
   return stepNavigator.isProcessed(item.code);
}
```

Run a command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

**Note:** Default item code is payment. When you complete the shipping and navigate to the payment step, it will return "shipping" in **isProcessed** function.

It will add the class even if the user comes to the checkout payment step by entering '#payment' manually.

Answer (score 1):

This works in magento 2.4.6 and also adds checkout step classes on page load (and change checkout step event).
Adjust the class names to your need.

Override progress-bar.js in you custom active theme(Path given below):

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/progress-bar.js

Add below code right after `stepNavigator.handleHash();` (but still inside the initialize: function).

Add class on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (location.hash === '#shipping') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('payment-step')
        .addClass('shipping-step');
}

if (location.hash === '#payment') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('shipping-step')
        .addClass('payment-step');
}
});
```

Add class on change checkout step event:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){

if (location.hash === '#shipping') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('payment-step')
        .addClass('shipping-step');
}

if (location.hash === '#payment') {
    $(document.body)
        .removeClass('shipping-step')
        .addClass('payment-step');
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new XML `checkout_index_index.xml` in your theme.

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

**Add below code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="my-custom-step"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: that will add the class name to all steps of the checkout.  I was hoping to add it to a single step

Comment: It's not possible to add class in single step because we have same layout in all steps